# Relationship between prime power and the divisor

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, sylow-theory

**Background**

When trying to prove that a group G has a non-trivial centre if its order is a power of a prime $p$, there involves a step in which we claim the number of left cosets of a centraliser subgroup is also a power of $p$.

**Problem**

Let $q|p^k$, then why are we sure that $q = p^i$ where $0\leq i <k$? In other words, why are we sure that $q$ can only be a power of $p$?

Comment: If it weren't, it wouldn't divide $p$ since $p$ is prime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ q|p^k \iff p^k \bmod q =0 \iff p^k=d \cdot q$$
However, $d$ can't be anything else but:
$$d=p^\lambda, \quad 0<\lambda\leq k $$

because $p$ is a prime ($p$'s powers have only divisors $1$ and other $p$'s powers) and thus
$$p^k=p^\lambda \cdot  q \iff q=p^{k-\lambda}=p^i, \quad 0 \leq i<k$$